# selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium

So basically I'm trying to make script in python that uses selenium webdriver to open and login to a website called marketsworlds and retrieve the market value of a stock. I have the script able to open and login into the page. I just cant figure out how to capture/get the market value and have it print out. I used inspect element to find the class:

```
<p class="market_value"> 

</p>
```

in between the open and close brackets inspect element displays the market value, which constantly changes.
I tried setting driver.find_element_by_class("market_value") to a variable and printing the variable. I get a print out of " at object 0x" and what ever comes after the x. any way to return what it actually displays?

Comment: share the url of webpage plz

Comment: the url is [link]https://marketsworld.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *have* to use Selenium for navigation, such as on JavaScript-heavy sites, It would suggest acquiring the page source and using an HTML parser to extract the data you want.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a great choice of parser. For example:

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Get *all* 'p' tags with the specified class attribute.
p_tags = soup.findAll('p',{'class':'market_value'})
for p in p_tags:
    print p.text
```

This should print to screen the text contained in the `<p>` tags with the class `market_value`. Its hard to give specifics without knowing the exact page source, however.

However, if you're determined to use strictly Selenium, you can find these elements by:

```
# Get *all* 'p' tags with the specified class attribute.
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('market_value')
for element in elements:
    print element.text

# or

# Get a *single* 'p' tag with the specified class attribute.
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('market_value')
print element.text
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I am kinda new to using python for extracting info from webpages. i decided to use selenium as a start. i would much rather use a different way if you have any suggestions that would achieve the same thing.

Comment: Take a look at [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). it might help shed some light on when Selenium is and is not required for scraping. Also take a look at the BeautifulSoup documentation I linked to in the answer. It will hopefully show you how easy HTML parsing is when done properly.